# how to do notification message in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

I have in Site.Master:

```
<% if(Session["msg"]!=null) Response.Write(Session["msg"].ToString()); %>
```

I have also on submit form method:

```
protected void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session["msg"] = "Thx for email.";
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

But now when I refresh page or go to another page I still see "Thx for email." but user should see it only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear out the `Session["msg"]` on `Page_load` (outside of the `if(!isPostback)`)

Or you can create a label on the master page, access that through the child pages to put the message in there, and clear that one on Page load, this gets you away from using Session.  Using a Label you can also set the cssClass, allowing bolding, color changes (red for errors, green for success, etc).

If you just want a plan message you could aways go with a literal control, less over head.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Session` variable having their value throghout the session.

```
Session["msg"]
```

will always have same value on all the pages in a session.

If you want that value should only be used for the page where you redirect then you can use `querystring`.

```
protected void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["msg"] = "Thx for email.";
  Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?msg='true'");
}
```

then on SiteMaster

```
<% if(Request.QueryString["msg"]!=null) Response.Write(Session["msg"].ToString()); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `Session["msg"] = null` after you show the message. Session lives in server at defualt of 20 min. If you do not set it null it will appeear

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Session["msg"] to null once it is printed on the page.